# Как в wordpress запустить cron задание в момент запуска ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, ajax, cors

Есть сайт на `wordpress`, в котором есть необходимость передать заполненные пользователем имя и телефон и отправить данные без перезагрузки в `cron` задание.

Но, пока не могу разобраться, можно ли с помощью `ajax` в принципе запускать `cron` задания или хуки.

На данный момент, данные пользователей `cron` запускаются только если страницу обновить или заново зайти на сайт.

**script.js**

```
    var datamail = {
        action: 'cronMail',
        name: $('input[name=first_name]').val(),
        tel: $('[name=phone]').val()
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: ajaxsettings.url,
        type: 'get',
        data: datamail,
        success: function (data) {
        },
        error: function (err) {
        }
    });
```

**functions.php**

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_cronMail',  'cronMail');
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_cronMail','cronMail');
wp_clear_scheduled_hook( 'mail_hook' );
add_action( 'mail_hook', 'mail_hook_function', 10, 2);

function cronMail(){
    $name = $_GET['name'];
    $tel = $_GET['tel'];
    wp_schedule_single_event( time() + 300, 'mail_hook', array( $_GET['name'], $_GET['tel'])); 
    spawn_cron();
    exit();
}

function mail_hook_function($name,$tel) {
    $message = 'Заявка от потенциального клиента '.$name.' с телефоном '.$tel;
    wp_mail( 'xoheyed253@brosj.net', 'Новая заявка от клиента', $message);
}
```

Comment: А почему cron, а не напрямую?

Comment: Cron так и работает - только при обращении к сайту. spawn_cron вызовет те хуки, чье время уже подошло, и не выполнит mail_hook, потому что он в будущем на 300 секунд

Comment: Используйте https://github.com/woocommerce/action-scheduler если вы уверены, что вам необходим крон

Comment: @KAGG Design потому что мне нужна задержка в 5 мин, это сокращенный вариант. В изначальном, идет проверка условия и если оно выполняется, то должен запускаться крон, не выполняется - другое действие. Не загромождал код, т.к. проверка - это вторичное и с ней проблем нет

Comment: @KAGG Design а как сделать так, чтобы он выполнил отложенный код?

Comment: @WP Punk поясните, пожалуйста, не понял как использовать

Comment: @WPPunk зачем ему action scheduler? Что он делает такого, что не сделает cron?

Comment: @Вася в чем проблема, ещё раз? Запущенное задание выполняется, если зайти на сайт через 5 минут, и не выполняется, если не заходить?

Comment: Если дело обстоит таким образом, то на сервере ставят серверный крон. На хостинге можно использовать первые 2 плагина отсюда https://wpmayor.com/best-cron-plugins-wordpress/

Comment: @KAGG Design не совсем, запущенное задание выполнится, если даже не дожидаясь 5 минут обновить страницу или перезайти и не выполнится, если больше не заходить

Comment: spawn_cron() тут не нужен

Comment: И clear_scheduled_hook надо перенести внутрь Ajax, перед wp_schedule

Comment: @KAGG Design поместил, но все тоже самое. `wp_schedule_single_event` сам по себе внутри не запускается, только если повторно зайти на сайт, в админку и т.п.

Comment: @Вася это обычное поведение крона в WordPress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cron так и работает - только при обращении к сайту. `spawn_cron` вызовет те хуки, чье время уже подошло, и не выполнит `mail_hook`, потому что он в будущем на 300 секунд.

Уберите `spawn_cron` из кода, он тут не нужен. Переместите `clear_scheduled_hook` внутрь ajax, перед `wp_schedule_single_event`.

После этого код будет работать так, как должен: событие откладывается на 5 минут, и срабатывает только, если происходит обращение к сайту. Поймите, это основополагающий принцип: сам код php никак не может быть запущен по таймеру, поэтому cron в WordPress - это псевдотаймер. При любом обращении к сайту проверяется, время каких назначенных событий уже прошло, и они выполняются.

На VPS сервере можно поставить серверный крон. Тогда серверное ПО будет дёргать сайт каждые, скажем, 5 минут, или 1 минуту. И WP cron будет срабатывать без обращений к сайту.

На хостинге так не получится. Но можно использовать внешний сервис easycron.com, там есть [инструкция](https://www.easycron.com/cron-job-tutorials/how-to-set-up-cron-job-for-wordpress), как настроить его для WordPress. После этого события cron будут выполняться по внешнему таймеру.